# Why do I receive a different runtime every time I run "time ./a.out" on the same program?

Tags: linux, runtime

I am currently trying to reduce the runtime of a kmeans program, however every time I run the "time ./a.out" command the terminal is giving me a different answer even though I haven't changed any of the code.  Does anyone have any idea why this is?

```
real    0m0.100s
user    0m0.082s
sys 0m0.009s
bash-4.1$ time ./a.out

real    0m0.114s
user    0m0.084s
sys 0m0.006s
bash-4.1$ time ./a.out

real    0m0.102s
user    0m0.087s
sys 0m0.005s
bash-4.1$ time ./a.out

real    0m0.099s
user    0m0.082s
sys 0m0.008s
bash-4.1$ time ./a.out

real    0m0.101s
user    0m0.083s
sys 0m0.006s
```

this is after running the same command consecutively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a modern system many many processes run in parallel (or better quasi parallel). That means the system switches between all processes. Note: it does not switch to the next process once one process is finished. That would mean processes would have to wait, get blocked. Instead each process gets a bit of time now and then, until it has finished.

The more processes, the slower the system altogether, the slower the single process gets when measured in absolute duration. That is what you see.

The typical strategy for this is called "round robin". You may want to google that term to read more about this topic.

Comment: How am I supposed to know if any changes I make to the code is actually reducing the runtime then, if the time command is giving me a constantly changing answer?

Comment: By doing a statistical measurement. You run the execution 1000 times and take the average execution time. You cannot get closer.

Answer (score 0):

First, let us understand that the `time` command will ["record the elapsed time or CPU Resource Used time"](http://ss64.com/bash/time.html) of the program. That translates to how much time the program runs on the processor. As you have noted, there are different times reported for each run of the program in all categories: Real time, User time, and System time.

Second, let us understand that modern systems will share the processor with all the other processes running on a system (only one process is in control of any core of the processor at any given time), and use many different schemes for how these processes share the processor and system resources, hence the different Real and User times. These times depend on how your system swaps out programs.

The sys time will depend on the program itself, and what resources it is requesting. As with any process, if the resources have been requested by another process, it will be put to sleep, waiting on the resource. Depending on the resource and how your particular system handles shared resources, a process may spend some idle time waiting for the resource and be put to sleep only after a timer times it out, or immediately if the processor can guess that the resource will take longer than the timer. Again, this is highly dependent on how your particular system handles these tasks, on your processor, and on the resources being requested.